# ¿Cómo remover un appendChild al completar el formulario?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Perdón que les pregunte algo tan *ridículo*, pero cuando intenté hacer las pruebas estaba saliendo.

En resumen, lo que quiero hacer es agregar un texto debajo del **input** para así poder avisar que hay un error o que no se completó correctamente.

Así que hice este código y que le da un color distinto al **input** y hace un texto con una etiqueta `p`. Mi pregunta es que ahora no me deja eliminar la etiqueta y creo que es porque el `removeChild` no está tomando bien al hijo.

Si alguien sabe cómo resolverlo se los agradecería. Desde ya muchas gracias y si saben cómo hacer este código "mejor" también estoy abierto a saber.

**Fragmento HTML:**

```html
<input id="inputDato" class="correcto" type="text" onFocus="vaciar(this)" onBlur="verificarEntrada(this)" value="nombre">
<div id="datosV" class="sinNada"></div>
```

**Fragmento JavaScript:**

```js
var inputDato = document.getElementById("inputDato");
var textoV = document.getElementById("datosV");

function vaciar(control) {
  control.value = "";
}

function verificarEntrada(control) {
  if (control.value == "") {
    // inputDato.style.border = '2px solid #EB5757';
    inputDato.classList.replace("correcto", "incorrecto");
    textoV.classList.replace("eliminar", "sinNada");

    let parrafo = document.createElement("div");
    parrafo.setAttribute("id", "texto");
    // parrafo.setAttribute("class","sinNada");

    textoV.appendChild(parrafo);
    let parrafoDOM = document.getElementById("texto");

    parrafoDOM.innerHTML = "Te falta completar datos";
    textoV.appendChild("texto");
  } else inputDato.classList.replace("incorrecto", "correcto");

  textoV.removeChild(textoV.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola en realidad con los pasos que haces en el código me despistas un poco, pero tomo lo que has hecho y lo que quieres hacer y sugiero este código:

```
var inputDato = document.getElementById('inputDato');
var textoV = document.getElementById("datosV");

inputDato.addEventListener('focus', ()=>{
    inputDato.value = '';
    textoV.innerHTML = '';
});

inputDato.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{
    if (inputDato.value == '') {
        textoV.innerHTML = "Te falta completar datos";
        inputDato.style.border = "1px solid red";
    } 
});
```

Con esto dejamos los eventos en el script y seleccionamos los elementos por el id. Cuando ocurre 'focus' limpiamos el input y el mensaje de error. Cuando ocurre 'blur' creamos el mensaje y le cambiamos el border al input.
Espero te ayude, saludos

Comment: hola Jose desde ya muchas gracias en la versión de prueba funciono perfecto.

ahora cuando quise ponerlo en mi codigo posta paso algo, te paso el Html por si sabes cual es el problema porque no me dejar poner el texto de la parte de abajo.

Comment: Si, pasamelo a ver como puedo ayudarte

Comment: hola José antes que nada gras por la predisposición, pero ya lo pude solucionar
Saludos